# change arrow placement in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

i have a UIPopoverController
however, due to design, i must place the arrow differently.
Again, this is arrow PLACEMENT, NOT ARROW DIRECTION

in other words, by default, the arrow is placed at the centre of the UIPopoverController like the follow:

```
 -----^-----
 |         |
 |         |
 |         |
 |_________|
```

i would like the following for my arrow placement

```
 --^--------
 |         |
 |         |
 |         |
 |_________|
```

is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: The arrow is not always in the center. But it always points to the view from which you are presenting the popover, for example a bar button item, and you can't change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrow actually points towards the rect that you provide in:

```
presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```

It appears in the center because the popover view tries to appear center-aligned with that provided rectangle. If you present the popover with that rect in a difficult-to-appear place such as a corner of the screen, it will get as close as it can, but won't necessarily be centered.

Unfortunately, you can't really change this behavior as it is internalized in the class, in order to preserve Apple/Cocoa UI guidelines and behavior.

Comment: so if i am not close to the corner of the screen, there is no way i can force it not to be centered aligned?  can i give it a rectangle of say 1 pixel, and ask it to position based on that?

Comment: Pretty much. You could give it a rectangle of 1 pixel, but if the 1 pixel rect wasn't near a corner (or side if you set the arrow to be up/down and put it near the left/right edge) it would attempt to center-align itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [popoverLayoutMargins](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/popoverLayoutMargins) and set the left margin as you need.